# Convert Side by Side 3D video to Anaglyph 3D

Tags: graphics, video, 3d, video-conversion, mencoder

As the title says, how should one convert a side by side 3D video (as is the condition of a 3D video, when downloaded) to anaglyph 3D?
I came across a few commands while searching for the solution, but didn't tried them as they were from too old posts and also I was not quite sure of the results.
These are the links that provided a solution for the mentioned problem:

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjM-6W4gaHTAhWIQI8KHX6oDW0QFggiMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmymemoryarea.blogspot.com%2F2013%2F10%2Flinux-3d-side-by-side-to-anaglyph-video.html&usg=AFQjCNGDaDxOX2BiNuzetlR7JFMza3NVWA&sig2=5lhS6bzYxj8KDG6j6OxrWQ

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjM-6W4gaHTAhWIQI8KHX6oDW0QFghWMAc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fubuntuforums.org%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D2191000&usg=AFQjCNHwDnsRNiefwWbg6dSo5eWk0JE7mA&sig2=wbus7eLVG9mk6I3wRmn2AA

Comment: link those posts in question, we'll let you know if those are still valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mencoder -vf stereo3d,scale sbs.mp4 -o anaglyph.mp4 -oac pcm -ovc x264`

where, 
`sbs.mp4` -> input video
`analglyph.mp4` -> output video

Does the work! But the stretch doesn't remains same. Still searching for that.
If someone knows how to stretch the output video, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Include `-force-avi-aspect 16:9` in the mencoder command (see below for complete command, or any other aspect ratio)

```
mencoder -vf stereo3d,scale sbs.mp4 -o anaglyph.mp4 -oac pcm -force-avi-aspect 16:9 -ovc x264
```